# How do I know when to shrink the size of a file after a write call?

Tags: python, linux, fuse

When my filesystem receives a call to `write()` with a buffer length that reaches outside of the current filesize, the program knows to increase the file size.

However, what if the file gets smaller? For example, what if I change the contents of a file from "hello" to "hell"? A call to write() is issued with offset 0 buffer length 4. If the filesystem follows these instructions and only updates the first 4 bytes of stored data without changing the file size, the next read will still show the same string.

How does my fuse implementation know when it is supposed to discard data at the end of the current buffer it's writing and shrink the size of the file?

So, how to differentiate between:

1. `example string` -> `write(offset=0, buf="hello")` -> `hello`
2. `example string` -> `write(offset=0, buf="hello")` -> `hellole string`

I am using [pyfuse3](https://www.rath.org/pyfuse3-docs/) but I suspect this logic to be universal across bindings in other languages.

Comment: It doesn't know, and it's *not* supposed to discard the data.  If you have a file with contents "hello" and you write "abcd" to the start of the file, then the new contents are "abcdo".  If you want to truncate the file, you need to call `ftruncate` or similar to explicitly tell the filesystem to shrink the file.  A `write` call will not shrink the file.

Comment: Discarding data beyond the end of a `write()` would never be done automatically; that requires an explicit truncate operation.  Looks like fuse reports this via a `setattr()` call, specifying `update_size` as the field to modify.

Comment: Why do you think it's _ever_ correct for the contents to be `hello` instead of `hellole string`?

Comment: (An alternative to an `truncate` call is an `open()` with a set of flags that includes `O_TRUNC`, but even then, it's not the `write()` that does the truncation).

Comment: @Shawn, eh? fuse certainly supports `truncate()`: https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#a103927b9fe73c5b7cb5ef43bccac5993

Comment: pyfuse3 doesn't have `truncate` but it does have [setattr](https://www.rath.org/pyfuse3-docs/operations.html#pyfuse3.Operations.setattr) with an `update_size` entry in `fields`. However, this was never used during my testing (`echo "something" > file; echo "shorter" > file`)

Comment: Yes, doing `truncate --size 4 file` does send setattr with fields.update_size to my filesystem but a redirect or editing the file in a text editor doesn't

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I didn't check for the `O_TRUNC` flag when opening a file, it turns out that the `truncate` command uses setattr while redirection in a shell uses `open` with `O_TRUNC` set.